# Bad state: Tried to read a provider that threw during the creation of its value. The exception occurred during the creation of type SomeBloc

Tags: flutter

I get this error while using **bloc** not provider.

while trying to add event to SomeBloc that is created before It gives this error :

```
======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following StateError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Bad state: Tried to read a provider that threw during the creation of its value.
The exception occurred during the creation of type EditFooterCubit.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _CreateInheritedProviderState.value (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:661:7)
#1      _CreateInheritedProviderState.debugFillProperties (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:750:44)
#2      _InheritedProviderScopeElement.debugFillProperties (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:585:20)
#3      DiagnosticableNode.builder.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:2945:17)
#4      DiagnosticableNode.builder (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:2948:8)
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#445b5
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: ready
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(188.8, 422.3)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(36.1, 20.3)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
====================================================================================================
```

This is where I create the bloc :

```
class EditFooterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static int pageNumber() => 5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return BlocProvider<EditFooterCubit>(
      create: (context) => EditFooterCubit(
        footerRepo: RepositoryProvider.of<FooterRepository>(context),
        footerBloc: BlocProvider.of<FooterBloc>(context),
      ),
      child: EditFooterForm(),
    );
  }
}
```

And here bloc is used to add event :

```
class EditFooterForm extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                   //here on button press error happens.
                   context.read<EditFooterCubit>().footerPreviewRequestedToState();
                },
                child: Text('UpdateFooterPart')),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            FooterPart(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I can't find why It gives error since I created this page like [LoginPage](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterlogintutorial?id=login-page) and Login Form Example in https://bloclibrary.dev/

Comment: Can you provide code of EditFooterCubit, there might be your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error indicates, **error occurred during creation of SomeBloc** .
So input parameters of SomeBloc **are not passed correctly**.

For example

```
SomeBloc({
    @required this.blocA,  
  })
```

SomeBloc needs BLocA and when you want to create SomeBloc you have passed BlocA like this  :

```
BlocProvider<SomeBloc >(
      create: (context) => SomeBloc (//here SomeBloc is the error causing bloc because
          blocA: BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context),//here BlocA is not accessible in this page or subtree so will give error 
          ),
      child: _View(),
    );
```

But BLocA is not accessible in this subTree.

So you should **Check the input parameters of the bloc that causes error**
and see whether you have passed the parameters correctly or not because the reason of error is that the passed parameters are not accessible in this subtree.